# remote installing of exe file fails to execute

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have a bit of a problem with getting the exe file to execute through remote sessions.

for now, my code looks a bit like this:

```
$session = new-pssession -computername *REDACTED*
Copy-item -path C:\Windows\Temp\Installer.exe -destination 'c:\' -ToSession
Start-Sleep -seconds 2
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {
   Start-Process C:\Installer.exe -argumentlist '/silent' -wait
}
$session | Remove-PSSession
```

This does copy the file, and I can see it in the C:\ folder on the client pc, but I can't get it to execute the exe file for the life of me.

No errors (even with /silent removed), no indicators of anything, it just doesn't execute.

Anybody have any idea?

If the information is needed, i am running Powershell v5 on both the DC and the client pc.

Comment: Try adding `-PassThru` to the `Start-Process` command and wrap it in `$(Start-Process ...) |Select ExitCode` - this will make the remote scriptblock return the exit code of the installer process on the remote machine once `Start-Process` returns

Comment: hello @mathiasR.Jessen I just now returned to work after a period of being sick and i have now tried the command you suggested, and the exitcode i get returned is -2147467259, if this tells you something

Comment: That's the Windows error code for "Access Denied"

Comment: i have now gotten so far as to i can get the code to run, and i can now open the task manager on the client pc and see it, so now i have gotten it to launch, but it just "dies out" uses 0 cpu power, and just stays there for an eternity to pass

Comment: You'll need to either consult the vendor documentation for the installer and/or [use procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to figure out why it exits early - no one here other than you has access to the systems in question :)

Comment: if i have any kinds of parameters on the command (like -wait, -passthru, etc) then it dies, but if i have no parameters, it goes through, and "finishes" but it never actually installs the software

Comment: ah... well, i guess i gotta try this procmon then and hope it will show me something. Thanks for the assistance anyways. Safe travels